# Python logging.exception in exception child class (i.e. a CustomError class that inherits from Exception)

Tags: python, exception, logging

I am trying to 'automate' the logging of exception information using python's built-in logging module whenever I raise a custom Exception class so that I don't have to write logger.exception(exception_message) every time in order to get the exception_info (sys.exc_info) part correctly in the logs, rather than NoneType: None.

With the following code I get 'NoneType: None' whenever a logger.exception line occurs instead of the appropriate sys.exc_info.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('exceptions_module')

class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_msg):
        super().__init__(error_msg)
        logger.exception(error_msg)

def forced_exception():
    try:
        raise Exception('some_exceptionh_occured')
    except Exception as error_msg:
        # Do some clean-up or other exception handling operations
        # ...

        # Now raise the exception as a custom error
        raise CustomError(error_msg)
```

Sometimes it is very beneficial to re-write low-level exceptions into "more human readable" and user-friendly error messages. (This is the main use case here)

So is there some way that doesn't lead me to writing 3 lines:

```
# [...]
    except Exception as error_msg:
        new_custom_error_msg = 'User-friendly message for:' + error_msg
        logger.exception(new_custom_error_msg)
        raise CustomError(new_custom_error_msg)
```

Another alternative came to mind, but still "forces" me to make extra effort for every exception raised, and that is to explicitly pass the 'correct' sys.exc_info() every time

```
from sys import exc_info as exception_info
# [...]
class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_msg, exc_info):
        super().__init__(error_msg)
        logger.exception(error_msg, exc_info=exc_info)
# [...]
    except Exception as error_msg:
        raise CustomError(new_custom_error_msg, exception_info())
```

I am *very* inclined to just explicitly add 'exception_info' *every time* I need to raise a CustomError...

**Any suggestions to make this leaner and avoid unnecessary code repetition?**

Comment: Look at python context managers. You can include logging and raising errors in one and use it by simply calling it with the exception object as a parameter: except CustomError as err: handle_error(err)